# React on link to element id

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've made a website for my friends. It's one page where you navigate by scrolling:

[www.hbzmusic.de](http://hbzmusic.de)

The both wish, that the different section could be targeted by direkt links such as *hbzmusic.de/Musik*.
So I decided to make a new directory /Musik (in the directory of index.php) with a new index.php simply linking back to the original one:

```
<?php
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    die();
?>
```

But so far I have no argument to pass for scrolling to the corresponding section. Some students at my university suggested using # to target the id of the desired element:

```
header('Location: ../index.php#Musik');
```

But as my scroll function is made in javascript I am searching for a possibility to catch this #Musik to scroll to this element.

I hope this question isn't as dumb as it seems and I am not wasting someones time :).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does the current scroll function look like? In the absence of any JavaScript, this simply works. If you have an `id="Musik"` that is.

Comment: The function gets an integer as input representing the index of the section. I made this via javascript to have interpolated smooth scrolling. So as Federico showed me, I now only use `index.php#1` for passing the index and then parsing it to an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With javascript you can catch the fragment identifier

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    // scrollingToHash(hash);
}
```